# How to refresh a listView once elements have been deleted via a Custom Adapter?

Tags: android, listview

In my custom adadpter (RequestAdapter), I delete elements dynamically. I do this by removing the object(s) from the ArrayList of objects that I pass through the constructor. Once I use remove() on the list, I invoke notifyDataSetChanged().

The issue is this - the item IS deleted from the original list, but all the items except the deleted item are appended onto the listView. (if I delete A from a list [A B C], the final result is a list that looks like this - [B C B C]. Further, if I delete B from this list, I get this - [C B C C]

Here's the code I use:

```
private HashMap<String,Object> tournamentStatus = new HashMap<>();

public RequestAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<RequestDetails> requests){
    super(context,0,requests);
    this.mRequestsList = requests;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    Log.d("Adapter getView()","Invoked");

    View listItemView = convertView;
    if(listItemView == null) {
        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.request_list_item, parent, false);
    }

    final RequestDetails retrievedRequest = getItem(position);

    final boolean isOCRequest;
    final boolean isParticipantRequest;

    final TextView tournamentName = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.request_textview_tournament_name);
    final TextView userName = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.request_textview_user_name);
    final TextView requestType = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.request_textview_request_type);
    final TextView sport = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.request_textview_sport);
    final TextView userFaculty = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.request_textview_user_faculty);
    final TextView userYear = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.request_textview_user_year);

    if(retrievedRequest.isParticipantRequest()) {
        requestType.setText("Request Type: Participant");
        sport.setText("Sport: "+retrievedRequest.getSport());
    }
    else {
        requestType.setText("Request Type: Organizing Committee");
        sport.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    tournamentRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Tournaments").child(retrievedRequest.getTournamentId());
    tournamentRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                TournamentInformation tournamentInformation = dataSnapshot.getValue(TournamentInformation.class);
                tournamentName.setText(tournamentInformation.getTournamentName());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


    userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(retrievedRequest.getUserId());
    userRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                UserInformation user = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserInformation.class);
                userName.setText("User Name: "+user.getName());
                userFaculty.setText("Faculty: "+user.getFaculty());
                userYear.setText("Year: "+Integer.toString(user.getYear()));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    Button mAcceptButton = (Button) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.accept_request_button);
    Button mDenyButton = (Button) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.deny_request_button);

    mAcceptButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(retrievedRequest.isParticipantRequest()){
                tournamentStatus.put("isOrganizing",false);
                tournamentStatus.put("isParticipating",true);
                userRef.child("sports").child(retrievedRequest.getTournamentId()).child(retrievedRequest.getSport()).setValue(true);
            }
            else if(retrievedRequest.isOCRequest()){
                tournamentStatus.put("isOrganizing",true);
                tournamentStatus.put("isParticipating",false);
            }


            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Requested Accepted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            userRef.child("tournamentStatuses").child(retrievedRequest.getTournamentId()).updateChildren(tournamentStatus);


            DatabaseReference requestsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Requests");
            requestsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                        for(DataSnapshot requestLooper : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                            RequestDetails loopedRequest = requestLooper.getValue(RequestDetails.class);
                            if(loopedRequest.equals(retrievedRequest)){
                                requestLooper.getRef().removeValue();

                                Log.d("Removing at",requestLooper.getRef().toString());
                                Log.d("requestList",mRequestsList.toString());

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
            mRequestsList.remove(retrievedRequest);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    mDenyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DatabaseReference requestsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Requests");
            requestsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                        for(DataSnapshot requestLooper : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                            RequestDetails requestDetails = requestLooper.getValue(RequestDetails.class);

                            if(requestDetails.equals(retrievedRequest)){
                                requestLooper.getRef().removeValue();

                                Log.d("Removing at",requestLooper.getRef().toString());
                                Log.d("requestList",mRequestsList.toString());

                                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Requested Denied",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

            mRequestsList.remove(retrievedRequest);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    return listItemView;
}
```

What changes do I make so that the list isn't duplicated?

**UPDATE** I added the entire adapter code, but most of it deals with setting textViews. I only do the deletion in the clickListeners of the Accept and Deny buttons

Comment: I guess the problem will be in other part of the code. Can you show full custom adapter code?

Comment: @josef.adamcik added the code

Comment: You are passing ArrayList with requests as constructor parameter to the adapter. Were does it come from? I suppose it's possible data in the list are duplicating somehow somewhere. Also I think you are not using firebase correctly - doing asynchronous queries in getView method will cause problems. (but I haven't used firebase yet myself so I don know the details) Try to do query for all data, prepare them into list and then just display them. The getView method should contain only: a) layout inflate when recycled view not provided, b) maping data from item to views.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want duplicates in a Collection,

```
List<String> al = new ArrayList<>();
```

//including duplicates list

```
private void removeDuplicate(ArrayList al)
{
    HashSet<String> hs = new HashSet<>();
    hs.addAll(al);
    al.clear();
    al.addAll(hs);
}
```

//change the list of add and delete after the called this method

removeDuplicate(al);

Comment: i'm sorry, could you please explain? What is the purpose of the hashSet? @            Buvan V

Comment: hashset to avoid ur dulicate values

Comment: once i use `al.addAll(hs);` , do I also need to make changes to the hashset everytime I want to delete an element? Like, right now I am deleting elements like this - `mRequestsList.remove(retrievedRequest);` . Do I need to change the contents of the hashSet and then modify the arrayList to add the new HashSet using `al.addAll(hs)` ? Sorry, I'm new to this

Comment: call this method from change the list after add or delete. removeDuplicate(al);

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your adapter properly. But I can give you a suggestion because I have faced this problem and I have found a way out for me. Not sure if it works for your problem but you can try:
After deleting the item from ArrayList you can write this code:

RequestAdapter.this.remove(getItem(position));

this code will remove the deleted item from the listView. Hope it will work. Thanks.